# Calculating the result of adding two velocities

Tags: typescript

I have a simple 2D system in which a velocity is represented as a speed (some value) and direction (an angle). If I have an object travelling at a given velocity *v*, when another velocity *v<sub>2</sub>* acts upon it I want to calculate the resultant velocity *v<sub>3</sub>*.

I have created the following illustration to explain the physics system I wish to implement. The speeds and angles may not be exactly correct because I do not know how to calculate them yet - that is the crux of this question - yet they serve as a fairly close guideline.

[image]

Is there an elegant solution for calculating the resultant velocities *v<sub>3</sub>*, when new velocity *v<sub>2</sub>* acts upon an object travelling at *v*?

Please note that I have a very limited understanding of mathematics but a good understanding of programming. I am coding in TypeScript but any answer in JavaScript, pseudo code, or very clear explanation (not riddled with cryptic mathematical symbols) is helpful.

Comment: Could you explain the values of v1, v2,... more? They need to consist out of two different values - either `direction and speed` or `x and y`. Depending on how v is represented, the formulas are different.

Comment: In addition, if v is represented as `direction and speed`, how is the direction (=angle) represented? Degrees (0 - 360)? Radiant (0 - 2*PI)? Percent (0 - 100)?

Comment: @maja My opening sentence explains that my vectors comprise speed and direction. You should be able to see from the image that angle *x* is specified in radians (*rad* for short).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution consists in converting to cartesian coordinates, add the coordinates there, then convert back to polar coordinates.

converting to cartesian:

```
x = speed * cos(direction)
y = speed * sin(direction)
```

back to polar:

```
speed = sqrt(x * x + y * y)
direction = atan2(y, x)
```

It might be a better idea to store your velocities in cartesian coordinates.

Edit: using your variable names: v, v2, v3, and angles a, a2, a3:

```
x = v * cos(a)
y = v * sin(a)

x2 = v2 * cos(a2)
y2 = v2 * sin(a2)

x3 = x + x2
y3 = y + y2

v3 = sqrt(x3 * x3 + y3 * y3)
a3 = atan2(y3, x3)
```

Comment: If the values of `v1` are represented as an angle (direction) and speed, your answer is better than mine.

Comment: Or you could just solve the whole problem in polar coordinates since that would save you both the trouble of converting and the inaccuracy it creates. The same principles apply regarding the calculations.

Comment: I don't understand this answer at all. I am dealing with two input velocities, *v* and *v2*, but I cannot see how they are plugged into this calculation because this answer makes no reference to either. I apologise but I am not very smart with numbers.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain more. I don't know typescript. Maybe the function names are a bit different there.

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript so the function names are exactly the same. Thanks Rémi I will give it a try now!

Comment: @Nit How would one do that?

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions https://sites.google.com/site/algebraii4sage/home/resources/stars-lessons/lesson-35-vector-addition-and-polar-coordinates

Comment: @Nit Can you express the solution as a procedural program?

Comment: @Nit It seems you are incorrect as I have implemented the method described in the linked document to add two vectors together, but since the formula uses `asin` instead of `atan2`, information about the correct quadrant is lost and so my y-axis is inverted. At least that is my best explanation for what I am now observing.

Comment: I don't understand how it would be possible to "solve the whole problem in polar coordinates". I don't believe there is a simpler and more accurate way to do (compared to my solution).

Answer (score 1):

So you have an object flying in the direction `v1`.
In order to support velocities, you just have to add them to `v1` for each frame / simulation step:

```
var v2;
while(simulation is running){
    v1 = v1 + v2;
}
```

You can represent `v1`, `v2` as vectors with the components `x` and `y`.

In order to convert you values, you can use `x = speed * cos(direction)` and `y = speed * sin(direction)` as supposed by Rémi.

Your addition will then look as follows:

```
v1.x = v1.x + v2.x;
v1.y = v1.y + v2.y;
```

In order to get the angle of a vector, you can use the formula `tan(angle) = y / x`, resulting in

```
angle = atan(y/x)
```

The according JavaScript call is `var angle = atan2(v1.y, v1.x);`.

The length of your vector (= speed of you object) can be calculated with

```
speed = sqrt(v1.x * v1.x + v1.y * v1.y)
```

Comment: arcsin won't get you the angle back. It will give you the same result if x is negated, for instance. Same for atan if you negate both. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: @Rémi I used the mathemetical notation for "arcus tangent", which is "arctan" or short "atan". `atan2()` is the function name in JavaScript, which can vary depending on the programming language used. I wanted to provide a generic solution, nothing JavaScript-specific.

Comment: I mean that atan and atan2 are two very different functions. From the wikipedia page: "The purpose of using two arguments instead of one is to gather information on the signs of the inputs in order to return the appropriate quadrant of the computed angle, which is not possible for the single-argument arctangent function".